# How to change the text color in dependency to the background

Tags: css

I'm creating an application for a paint shop. They have a lot of colors (> 4000)

To show the color, I create a badge with the color as background color.

```
.custom_badge {
   background-color: var(--bg);
   border-radius: 10px;
   height: 25px;
   padding: 0px 10px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: 500;
}
```

If the background color is as example yellow, I like to show the text in black. If the background color is dark, i like to show the text color white.

I searched for inherit.

Is there a way with `inherit`?

Or is there an onther solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way in CSS to do this, but it can be done with Javascript :

```
let RGB = window.getComputedStyle( document.body ,null).getPropertyValue('background-color');  

RGB = RGB.replace(/[rgb \(\)]/gim, '');
RGB = RGB.split(',');

let textColor = (RGB[0]+RGB[1]+RGB[2]<300) ? '#fff' : '#000';
console.log(textColor);
```